# Remove quotation marks around header in the output from write.csv

Tags: string, r, csv, io, header

I have a 2 x 2 `csv` such as:

```
A,B
1.12,1.24
```

If I read it into `R` and then overwrite the old file without doing anything, it'll now print in terminal as:

```
"A","B"
1.12,1.24
```

How do I stop this from occuring? The `R` code:

```
dat <- read.csv(filePath,header=FALSE,sep=",",skip=1)
colNames <- strsplit(readLines(filePath,1),",")[[1]]
colnames(dat) <- colNames
write.csv(dat,filePath,row.names=FALSE)
```

Note that `dat` in the above MWE is a `data.frame`.

Comment: `cat(dat)` - the quotation marks are not really there. They signify the data is of type `"character"`.

Comment: Can you please explain why you use `header=FALSE`, and then add headers again using `colnames`. Also note the `quote` argument in `write.csv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- read.csv(text = "A,B
1.12,1.24")

df
#      A    B
# 1 1.12 1.24

write.csv(x = df, file = "df.txt", quote = FALSE)
```

df.txt then looks like this in Notepad:

```
,A,B
1,1.12,1.24
```